# How to solve the problem of using modules to configure environment variables and losing them when starting tmux？

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

I'm trying to use the [modules](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) program to configure my linux computer's environment variables. I add the following command to add environment variables to my bashrc.

```
module load gcc/5.5
```

I expect to use the above command to add `gcc5.5/bin` to `$PATH`. If I open a new terminal, `gcc5.5/bin` is in `$PATH`, but if I use a tmux command, `gcc5.5/bin` is not added.

Comment: what do you mean by "open a new terminal" and "use a tmux command"?

Comment: and where do you call `module load gcc/5.5`?

Comment: I add "module load gcc/5.5“ to my bashrc, so If I open a new terminal, PATH environment has gcc home path. Then I try to start a tmux that is a terminal multiplexer, gcc home path is not added to PATH environment.

Comment: please clarify how do  you "open a new terminal"? like Gnome Terminal or something?

Comment: and i think it's not the `modules` util's problem. please try manually setting `$PATH` in your bashrc and see if it works. if the problem still exists please get rid of `modules` in the question so people dont need to learn about `modules` first.